# MySQL using FLOOR leads to unexpected result

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I have the following formula:

`SELECT FLOOR(38774/184*126*23+0.5);`

Which to my surprise yields `610690` even though the result of formula inside `FLOOR` is `610691`. In Excel this works just fine and gives me the desired result, also in any calculator I use on macOS or Windows.

Am I overlooking something here? Is there an explanation for this behavior and more importantly how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point calculations are quite a funny thing: Try these:

```
SELECT FLOOR(38774/184*126*23+0.5);
SELECT FLOOR(38774*126*23/184+0.5);
SELECT FLOOR(ROUND(38774/184*126*23+0.5, 3));
```

What's going on here?

The most important part is, that `38774/184` has no exact representation as a floating point number - you always and up a tiny bit short. With the rest of the calculation adding up to exactly 610691, you end up a tiny bit short of 610691 resulting in a `FLOOR` of 610690.

The second line avoids this, by regrouping the parts of the calculation to a sequence, that does have an exact representation as a floating point number.

The third line uses a `ROUND` to cut off the very small difference, thus making the `FLOOR` work as expected.

Rule of thumb: Floating point numbers don't produce exact results. While they most often are "exact enough", there are edge cases where they aren't. You just hit one, and quite a usual one: Converting back to integer via `FLOOR` or `CEIL`.

Now to answer your question: From Experience I would have ordered the calculation the way the 2nd line does - bigger numbers (within INT32 range) are much more likely to produce the correct `FLOOR`. If the computational cost is acceptable to you, I'd go for

```
SELECT FLOOR(ROUND(38774*126*23/184+0.5, 3));
```

and be quite confident to have all edge cases covered.

Comment: I'm actually using this to mimic the Excel rounding behaviour on an embedded MySQL database where I can't change the mode. How does the `ROUND` affect this? My approach was like `FLOOR(x*100+0.5)/100`. So in your example with `ROUND` the following is rounded "wrongly": `FLOOR(ROUND(4.994999999*100+0.5,3))/100=5.00` instead of `4.99`